# Glide takes lot of time to load image in Image view

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-glide

I am using glide to load image in image view but it is taking lot of time to show the image in image view. I am loading the picture from my custom camera in the image view. Every thing is working but it takes a lot of time to load the image here is the code:

```
    private void show_image_from_custom_camera(byte[] data) {
     bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); 
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); bitmap_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);

                int screenWidth = width;
                int screenHeight = height;
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(data)
                        .asBitmap().centerCrop()
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(width,height) {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                // you can do something with loaded bitmap here

                                // .....
                                int w = resource.getWidth();
                                int h = resource.getHeight();
                                // Setting post rotate to 90

                                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                                mtx.postRotate(90);
                                // Rotating Bitmap
                                Bitmap realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(resource, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
                                photo_setter.setImageBitmap(realImage); //setting the image in image-view
                            }
                        });



            }
```

Is there anything that will reduce this time? I want to show image in image view at a faster rate.

Comment: does it show fast enough if you don't rotate the bitmap?

Comment: No it takes the same time.

Comment: what is the resolution of your bitmap?

Comment: well glide appears to be useless in this case, because you already decode the bitmap, save it and decode it again using glide. My suggestion is to run this code 
`bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);`
async

Comment: I have edited the code now all these line as you suggested are removed i FORGOT to remove them @Belzebub

Comment: @Belzebub as you suggested these 3 line takes more time then glide

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Belzebub .Well I am have made a serious mistake and I forgot to remove the first 3 line of the code that are :

```
    bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); 
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bitmap_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
```

Without them everything is working fine and I am loading image in image view with faster speed now I am keeping this post so that anyone wants to load image in image view on Camera.PictureCallback can use this code without the top 3 lines.